# jQTouch on Iphone - jumping to specific DIV after onclick and javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, jqtouch

I am just starting to use jQTouch. 
In `#contact` I have a button that calls javascript function `sendEmail()`

How can I jump to/show the div `#statusDiv` in the javascript function after sending the email?

```
    function sendEmail() {
        // sending email

        // --> how to jump to DIV called statusDiv
    }

<div id="home" class="current">    
</div>

<div id="contact"  >
    <ul class="rounded">
      <li ><a id="emailButton" onclick="sendEmail()">Stuur email</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="statusDiv">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the goTo function from the jQtouch object. Something like:

```
jQT.goTo('#statusDiv')
```

Answer (score 1):

In latest version you can use

```
jQT.goTo('#statusDiv',"slideleft");
```

first argument is division name and second one is animation.